# Should each microservice run in its own process?

Tags: deployment, soa, microservices

Assume I have separated my monolithic application into 5 microservices.

Now do I need to run these 5 microservices in 5 processes or is it OK to have all 5 of them run in a single process? Why?

Answer (score 4):

The very purpose of choosing to go with Microservice Architecture is to achieve scalability and agility through independence of services. Here is an excerpt from a [good article on the matter, you might find interesting](https://smartbear.com/learn/api-design/what-are-microservices/). It is by a pretty credible source - SmartBear (the creators of SOAPUI):

> While there is no standard, formal definition of microservices, there
>   are certain characteristics that help us identify the style. 
>   Essentially, microservice architecture is a method of developing
>   software applications as a suite of independently deployable, small,
>   modular **services in which each service runs a unique process** and
>   communicates through a well-defined, lightweight mechanism to serve a
>   business goal.

So yes, you should absolutely go for deployment as separate processes. You will be much more flexible this way. For example, running all 5 services in a single process could make it impossible to hot-swap new versions of single microservices without stopping all the others (even though they might not be logical interdependence between all services).

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what "process" means in this context? Is it more a conceptual thing (like a business process) or physical (like a thread or something)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @dzenesiz IIRC, the context of the question here, and hence the answer, was about processes as in executing instance (physical), and not in the sense of business processes. But logic-wise, with Microservices, you should still have them in a way that each microservice revolves around its own separate set of related functions or context in a domain. The idea of microservices is to have them designed in a way that is logical and not do hundreds of them, just because you can. I hope this helps.

Comment: Helps a lot. Thanks for taking the time to clarify.